# Use a string key as v-model in v-item-group

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

It is possible to use a string key as v-model on v-item-group?

in data area I have this

```
    payment: null,
    payments: [
      {
        icon: 'mdi-alpha-p-circle-outline',
        type: 'paypal',
      },
      {
        icon: 'mdi-credit-card-outline',
        type: 'credit',
      },
      {
        icon: 'mdi-cash',
        type: 'cash',
      },
    ],
```

in template Area i have this:

```
<v-item-group v-model="payment" class="row">
  <v-item v-for="payment in payments" :key="payment.type">
    <template v-slot="{ active, toggle }">
      <v-col class="text-center" cols="4">
        <v-card
          :class="active ? 'success--text' : 'grey--text'"
          class="mb-6 mx-auto pa-10 d-inline-block v-card--account"
          outlined
          @click="toggle"
        >
          <v-icon large v-text="payment.icon" />
        </v-card>

        <div
          class="text-uppercase subtitle-2 text--primary"
          v-text="payment.type"
        />
      </v-col>
    </template>
  </v-item>
</v-item-group>
```

To obtain this

[image: payment options]

When I select the payment type the v-model take a numeric value, for example:

if I select PayPal the payment value is 0
if I select credit the payment value is 1
& if ai select cash the payment value is 2

[image: data values]

I checked on vue console the item-groups id and there are ok

[image: vue console]

How can I use the payment.type of selected item as v-model?

I will appreciate any help.

Jose Rodriguez

Comment: Would you mind creating a simple [mre]?

Comment: v-model of v-item-group will always be tied to the index as with a lot of list style models. If you need to access the text value, create a computed data that will use the index from v-model to return the string value. Soemething like `if (this.payment > -1) return this.payments[this.payment].type`

Answer (score 0):

There are so many way you can alter the value of parent's `payment` property. You can edit the `toggle` method so that it changes `payment` property. You can also use `event -  listener` to set `payment` property. Unless you provide a snippet to play around, these are what I can suggest so far.